# Is it compulsory to have a boarding pass at the immigration booth?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tickets

When an EU/EFTA citizen enters a non-EU country which is visa free, do they need to have their boarding pass on hand at the immigration booth? One can simply lose their boarding pass during the flight and I wonder if not having a boarding pass at arrival can pose any problem!?

Comment: Surely the rules depend on the country (see [comment about Thailand](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121844/is-it-compulsory-to-have-a-boarding-pass-at-the-immigration-booth#comment299713_121845)).  But why limit the question to countries that are visa-free for EU/EFTA citizens?  Are there any such visa exemptions that depend on the traveler's point of origin?  I'm unaware of any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know no country in the world which requires the boarding pass at arrival immigration (unless getting a visa on arrival is dependent on where you arrive from, such as for US citizens in Baku).

In fact I always leave the boarding pass on the aircraft since I no longer need it after boarding the flight.

At immigration I only show my passport or (in Europe, Turkey, Georgia and overseas France) ID card

Comment: `I no longer need it after boarding the flight` Not sure if it always the best choice. Some landing cards i.e. UK, Australia etc ask for the incoming flight number. If caught at immigration for some check ( food, customs etc) the boarding card might come handy.

Comment: @DumbCoder On most airlines you get the landing card on the plane (Ryanair being a notable exception), but the UK officers at least will know your flight number thanks to API anyway, and leaving a single field blank shouldn't be the whole world

Comment: @DumbCoder Never been stopped by customs so can't say much about that.

Comment: Not for immigration, but there are some few airports where arriving passengers are allowed tax-free purchases and need to show their boarding card for that purpose.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Question was about immigration though

Comment: @Coke Sure. I just wanted to point out that it is not *always* a good idea to leave the boarding pass on the aircraft, assuming that it is no longer needed.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Didn't say it was, just that it's how I personally do it

Comment: I was only asked for my boarding pass once, upon arrival to Sao Paolo, Brasil, with a passport that did not require me having a visa. It was glanced at and handed back to me. Additionally, I always take photos of, and save my boarding passes until I'm sure the appropriate mileage has been credited to my frequent flyer accounts.

Comment: Thai immigration consistently and explicitly ask to present your BP on arrival.

Comment: @ach Oh, OK. Was going to Bangkok last autumn but cancelled it - would've been interesting as I always leave the BP on the plane.

Comment: I used to keep it until the miles had been posted on my account, but now with mobile boarding passes etc...

Comment: @Coke leaving the boarding pass on the plane is not a good idea, if you have further flights in the same booking. There are several talks and presentations about how to use information on the boarding pass to access the reservation (and even change or cancel it).

Comment: @Coke: when traveling with baggage, the baggage receipt is attached on boarding pass. This is checked more often. So if you are used to trash, you risk to trash also important information (and with boarding pass, one can log into your travel data and ask for refund (in case of multiple segments).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the baggage receipt is not always attached to the boarding pass, and even if it is you can remove it and place it elsewhere.

Comment: Israeli immigration asked for my boarding pass. I had lost it and the agent shrugged, asked me what flight I had been on, and let me in without further comment on that.